# Get report path from project folder in win-forms

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I get a Crystal Report into my Winforms App like this From Drive:

```
 rpd.Load("C:\\EmpRep\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
```

I want to load from this project folder, but I get an error. How can I fix this?

```
 rpd.Load("Reports\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
```

Comment: So sounds like you just want to convert "Reports\CrystalsReport2.rpt" from  a relative path to an absolute path. Try Path.GetFullPath [https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true]

Comment: Or if the report file is not in the working directory, you can use Path.Combine to build the path - Path.Combine(folder, "Reports\CrystalReport2.rpt")

Comment: Thanx for ur reply report file is in working dir only i want to load it from working dir only...

Comment: In that case, what about
`rpd.Load(Path.GetFullPath("Reports\\CrystalReport1.rpt");`

Comment: Not Working ... Error is 'Employee.ConClass.GetFullPath(string)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial ...

Comment: Looks like you've picked up the wrong Path class - try **System.IO**.Path.GetFullPath instead. And before you pass it down, see what path you're getting - to confirm that the rpt file is being picked up from the right folder.

Comment: I Have also tried with this but not working Error is same load report failed my code is this                                                                                      string path2 = @"\Reports\CrystalReport2.rpt";  rpd.Load(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path2));

Comment: You misunderstood - find out exactly what you get back from System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path2). And then confirm whether it is the right path.
The other possibility is that Crystal Reports may need you to change the current working directory.

Comment: The path i've given is correct, in my project Reports is a folder and i have a report in that folder. folder is present in working dir only

Comment: Sorry, just want to be completely clear (because I'm running out of ideas). When you compile and run, presumably you'll be running from bin\debug or bin\release. So you Reports folder is a subdirectory of that is it? There's no point it being a subdirectory of your project if it doesn't also make it to run directory. You may need to set the build action for your rpt file to be Content to get it copied. If that isn't it, I'm sorry, I can't help any more.

Comment: Thank you for ur message actually it is always working fine for web-forms ... am getting error in win-forms only am sorry am not mentioned that in my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
rpd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
```

Comment: Not Working ... Error is Load report failed